# create axioms from excel workbook

Tags: owl, protege

I'm using protege 5.5 for creating axioms from xlsx file 
Is there a way to add rules for Arabic text?

such as:

```
{ Individual: @A2
   Types: @A1
   Facts: 
         اعراض @B2 }
```

and can I find a way to import from file other than xlsx as XML or csv ??

Thank you